# Converting a list of comma delimited strings to a list of list of ints

Tags: f#

I have a data set like such

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
9,0
```

When I read it using ReadAllLines I get an array of strings. So far I've converted an strings to an array of lists that contains strings such as

```
[["1";"2"];["3";"4"]... etc
```

I need one last step to get this `[[1;1;[1;4]... etc`

My code right now:

```ml
module Data =
    let load(path : string) (filename : string) =
        System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path + "\" + filename) 
        |> Array.toList
        |> Seq.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|] |> Array.toList)
        |> Seq.map (fun s -> s |> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse)
```

This is what it returns when I test it

```
val it : seq<seq<int>> = seq [seq [1; 2]; seq [3; 4]; seq [5; 6]]
```

I'm expecting something like this

```
val zz : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, now you only have to convert the sequence of sequences to a list of lists:

```
|> Seq.map Seq.toList
|> Seq.toList
```

and you can remove the line `|> Array.toList` it's better in this case to work with sequences and then convert to lists as last step.

Also note that you can use `System.IO.Path.Combine(path, filename)` which will handle the logic of combining the path with the filename for you.

Finally there is some refactoring you can do:

```
|> Seq.map (fun s -> s |> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse)
```

Applying [eta reduction](https://www.google.ch/#q=eta+reduction) you can remove the lambda:

```
|> Seq.map (Seq.map System.Int32.Parse)
```

then

```
|> Seq.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|] |> Array.toList)
|> Seq.map (fun s -> s |> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse)
|> Seq.map Seq.toList
```

can be simplified to a single `map` since `x |> map f |> map g` is equivalent to `x |> map (f >> g)`

```
|> Seq.map ( (fun s -> s.Split [|','|]) >> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse >> Seq.toList)
```

eliminate parenthesis:

```
|> Seq.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|] |> Seq.map System.Int32.Parse |> Seq.toList)
```

You can remove the intermediate value `lines` and type annotations since `Combine` expects two strings. Here's the full code:

```
open System
module Data =
    let load path filename =
        IO.File.ReadAllLines(IO.Path.Combine(path, filename))
            |> Seq.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|] |> Seq.map Int32.Parse |> Seq.toList)
            |> Seq.toList
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `List.map` instead of `Seq.map`:

```
[|"1,2"; "3,4"; "5,6"; "7,8"; "9,0"|]
|> Array.toList
|> List.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|] |> Array.toList)
|> List.map (fun s -> s |> List.map System.Int32.Parse)
```

Since you have two `map`s in a row, you can combine them:

```
[|"1,2"; "3,4"; "5,6"; "7,8"; "9,0"|]
|> Array.toList
|> List.map (fun s -> s.Split [|','|] |> Array.toList |> List.map System.Int32.Parse)
```

Result in both cases:

```
> 
val it : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]; [5; 6]; [7; 8]; [9; 0]]
```